# Using XPCOM components from Mozilla Add-on SDK

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xpcom, firefox-addon-sdk

I have worked on Mozilla Add-on Development in the past (beginner level). But on encountering XPCOM, I got really scared and left it in the middle.

Recently only I encountered Add-on SDK and found it to be really cool, and it was really fascinating to see that the work that took months before was not more than 2 days work with the SDK. Now again I am stuck on the XPCOM module.

Now I really want to exploit the power of XPCOM but it will take me at least a week to get familiar with XPCOM in the context of SDK. What code do I need to obtain the functionality that I desire?

1. For each user session, I want to log something. I am able to differentiate sessions. What I want now is the code to create a file in the user's machine, open it from the add-on and write something onto it.
2. Code to access the bookmarks and downloads and to read them.

It would really be a heart-breaking moment if I would have to switch back from SDK.

Comment: How did you manage to get the _hello world_ work? Would you mind to share some references with me? What I always get is `Cc['my contract id'] is undefined`. You might get some rep if you kindly answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477794/firefox-xpcom-hello-world-typeerror-cc-is-undefined).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`chrome` package](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.1/dev-guide/module-development/chrome.html) gives you full XPCOM access. For file access it is best to use the [`FileUtils` module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_code_modules/FileUtils.jsm):

```js
var {Cc, Ci, Cu} = require("chrome");
var {FileUtils} = Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");
var file = FileUtils.getFile("ProfD", ["mylogfile.txt"]);
var stream = FileUtils.openFileOutputStream(...);
stream.write(data, data.length);
stream.close();
```

The somewhat unusual syntax to import the module is due to [bug 683217](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=683217). Note that `FileUtils.openFileOutputStream()` is only available starting with Firefox 7 and `FileUtils.openSafeFileOutputStream()` isn't usable if you want to append to a file.

For bookmark access you use the usual [code snippets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Bookmarks#Firefox_3), starting with:

```js
var bmsvc = Cc["@mozilla.org/browser/nav-bookmarks-service;1"]
              .getService(Ci.nsINavBookmarksService);
```

Comment: I get this exception on running your code..

**TypeError: FileUtils.getFile is not a function**

Does it require anything else to be included in the directory structure of Add-on? I just simple copy pasted your code with **file** variable being passed to **openFileOutputStream** function.

Comment: @Shatu: Sorry, my bad - so much about posting code without testing it. `Cu.import()` doesn't return the `FileUtils` object but rather an object with `FileUtils` as a property. Fixed my code in the answer, also the parameters of `FileUtils.getFile()`.